# Файлы загружаются в оперативную память, а нужно на диск (Retrofit + RxJava)

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava

Файлы загружаются в оперативную память, а нужно на диск

```
class DownloadInteractorImpl
    @Inject constructor(api: ApiService)
            : BaseInteractor<ApiService>(api), DownloadInteractor {
    override fun downloadFile(url: String): Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> {
        return api.downloadFile(url)
    }
}
```

Функция saveFile вызывается после того как весь файл был загружен в оперативную память

```
class PreviewPresenterImpl
    @Inject constructor(view: PreviewView,
                        private val context:Context,
                        private val interactor: DownloadInteractor,
                        private var disposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable())
{
    fun loadFiles(pathways: ArrayList<String>) {
        for (fileUrl in pathways) {
            disposable.add(interactor.downloadFile(fileUrl)
                .flatMap(this::saveFile)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(
                        { file -> view.onFileLoadedComplete(file!!.absolutePath) },
                        { error -> Log.e("TAG", "error loading file", error) }
                )
            )
    }


    fun saveFile(response: Response<ResponseBody>): Observable<File?> {
        return Observable.fromCallable(object : Callable<File?> {
            override fun call(): File? {
                var sink: BufferedSink? = null
                var resultFile:File? = null
                try {
                    val header = response.headers().get("Content-Disposition")
                    val fileName = header!!.substring(22, header.length - 1)

                    val file = File(context.cacheDir, Util.cacheDir + fileName)

                    file.parentFile.mkdirs()

                    sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(file))
                    sink.writeAll(response.body()!!.source())
                    sink.close()
                    sink = null

                    resultFile = file
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.e("TAG", javaClass.simpleName + ": error save file!", e)
                } finally {
                    if(sink != null)
                        sink.close()
                }

                return resultFile
            }
        })
    }
}
```

какие изменения нужно внести что бы загружаемые данные сохранялись сразу в файл (обычно создается промежуточный буфер например 1024 байт)